# Subgroup of $S_n$ is divisible by $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

> Suppose that $G$ is subgroup of $S_n$ and for each $ i, j\in \{1, 2, ..., n\}$ there exists $\sigma \in G$ such that $\sigma(i) = j$. Prove that $n \mid |G|$.

Suppose i is fixed. for each j we can find $\sigma$ such that $\sigma_{ij}(i) = j$ and $\sigma_{ij}(i) $ and $ \sigma_{ik}(i)$ are distinct. for each i we can find {$\sigma_{i1}, ..., \sigma_{in}$}. so we have found n(n-1)/2. I have problem proving that if $\sigma_{ij} = \sigma_{kl} $ then n | |G|

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $G$ acts transitively on the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, and use the Orbit Stabilizer theorem.